# Is it too much to email an editor thanking them for sending a paper for review?

Tags: editors

I was thinking of thanking the editor for considering the paper and I look forward to hearing reviewer’s comments making changes if need be. Does this seem unprofessional or strange?

Comment: Yes it is too much.

Answer (score 33):

No need to do this. I wouldn't necessarily say it rises to the level of unprofessionalness, but it is "noise".

It's fine to include a *brief* thank you just out of politeness if you have some other reason for correspondence, but I definitely wouldn't send an email simply to thank, and there is no correspondence needed at this time.

Comment: Moreover, thanking the editor for sending your paper for review conveys the impression that you thought your paper might not really be good enough for the journal.

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest against it. This is their job. The note would be just noise. Save your thanks for the final disposition of your paper, if at all, or, more appropriately, for some action beyond the minimal requirements of their job.

It isn't *bad* to do it, just a distraction.

Answer (score -10):

That is fine, just be brief:

> Dear [editor], I just received the notification that our manuscript been sent out for review. Please let me know if there is anything more we should do. Thank you, Sincerely, [corresponding author]

Thanking editor will not change anything or influence the process at all

Comment: At the very least, doing this will signal a lack of experience. I don't see any advantage in sending such an email.

Comment: If you know the process and still ask for instructions how to proceed that risks the editor wasting their time in pointing the next steps out to you. Thereby potentially turning a potential tiny social pro (sending an explicit thank your doing their job) into a con by slightly annoying the editor with additional work that in this case is even unnecessary.